# compare subjective participants choices

Tags: categorical-data

I am categorising photographs into one of three categories based on a subjective appraisal of the photo contents.
I wanted to test how 'subjective' the method is by asking 7 other people to classify 100 images and compare their decisions to mine.
71% of the images received 'mostly' the same category i.e. at least 5 people out of the 7 agree on the category.
I personally dont think this is high enough agreement to rely on this method, but is there a way of testing this statistically?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ive found it - Cohens Kappa for inter-rater reliability